# Only allow certain IPs to use an HTTP port

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I'm running Ubuntu and am setting up a development server for my website. I only want the IP from my workstation to be able to access the website. Is there anyway to setup a firewall rule for this?

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The typical way to do this would be in the web server's config; that's where I'd recommend putting it.  For Apache:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.1.1.49
```

But, if you're inclined toward blocking connections altogether, you can do that, too.  Ubuntu provides a simplified iptables interface called UFW:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 10.1.1.49 to any port 80/tcp
sudo ufw deny 80/tcp
```

Comment: I know iptables inside and out, but didn't know about ufw: learned something new today. It seems to be included in Debian Squeeze as well. http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ufw